# Create a partition with Mint intaller iso

Tags: partitioning, linux-mint, iso-image

Since I like messing around with my OS and have a tendency to break something in the process, I would like to make a partition in my hard drive that would hold the install iso for what-ever os I am using. I would then edit my grub menu to recognize this iso so I could boot off it and reinstall my os, provided that the way I break things next time is not to break the boot loader. Currently I am using Linux Mint but I am looking into trying elementary and pear. I have 2 questions: (1) would this actually work, i.e. would one partition be able to install on another or are issues with mounting or maybe something else (2) if yes to (1) how would I actually go about doing this, I've been tinkering with the install (of mint, in this specific case) and it keeps doing very weird stuff like making my root partition and extra partition for my iso both external to the regular file system... which makes me wonder where it installed the main files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done. You will need a new bootloader (it's called gujin, and you can find it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gujin/)), and you will have to follow the instructions discussed on this [Ubuntu forum page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=666267).

However, it seems to me it offers very little advantage over keeping a USB key always ready to the rescue.